# Are there different platform materials besides wood?

Tags: starbound

The post title says it all, really. I'm planning out my main house and as far as I can tell, my only choice for a staircase is wood. Not exactly the nicest material.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I have not found blueprints for other types of platforms, most dungeons will have their own specific themed type of platform, which can be mined and reused. I've found steel platforms, temple platforms, and vine platforms so far.

Comment: I'd love to say that this game deliberately encourages you to steal everything that isn't nailed down. Except that's clearly not a problem.

Comment: @millimoose: First you steal everything that isn't nailed down. Then you steal the nails. And then you steal everything that isn't nailed down again. ;)